# How to turn INPUT element to readonly with Enter or Escape key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<input>` element set to readonly by default:

```
<input readonly type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this)">
```

If the user double-clicks this element it will be set to editable with:

```
function onDoubleClick(elem){
    var element = $(elem);
    if (element.prop('readonly')==true) { element.prop('readonly', false);}
    else { element.prop('readonly', true); }
```

This `<input>` element will stay editable up until the user double-clicks it again. I wonder if there is a way to link an `Enter` key and the `Escape` key so the user could end the input by hitting one of those keyboard keys turning the  `<input>` element back to readonly again. How to achieve it?

Comment: Why would you _want_ this to be your user experience? Why does it ever need to be disabled if the user can enter data into it just by enabling it? It seems like an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this working solution that works with the **ENTER** key. Hope it helps!

**Updated Solution**

```js
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function(event){

 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13'){
        if ($(this).prop('readonly')=== false) {
        $(this).prop('readonly', true); 
        }
        else { 
        $(this).prop('readonly', false); 
        }
    }
});
        
function onDoubleClick(elem){
    var element = $(elem);
    
    if (element.prop('readonly')=== true) {
        element.prop('readonly', false);
        if(!element.val()){
          element.val(".").val("");
        } 
        else{
        element.val($.trim(element.val(element.val()+" ").val()));
        }
    }
    else { 
        element.prop('readonly', true); 
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this)"/>
```

Comment: You really want to set the `keydown` handler outside `onDoubleClick`, because as it is, this is a memory leak: those handlers will multiply with every edit.

Comment: That works well. I probably would just use `element.on('keydown', function(e) {..}` since we have the `element` already in place.

Comment: @alphanumeric I just updated my answer to use element instead of $('input[type=text]') . I'm glad I was able to help!.

Comment: @HenryDev @alphanumeric When double click on the input, the input begin `focus`, but I can't find the **cursor** in it when it empty? default performance of change `readonly`, the text all be pitched on, may I change this? I wanna when I double click the input, the cursor appeared in the end of line?

Comment: Can we link the `<input>` element's `keydown` event at the time the elements is being declared?. ..instead of linking its `keydown` event inside of `onDoubleClick` function? `Amadan` is correct, linking the element's event inside of `onDoubleClick` function results to a memory leak: as many times the `<input>` element is double clicking as many times the `keydown` even will be fired or triggered when the same element is double clicked again...

Comment: @Tomlsion I have updated my solution. The cursor will show up right away after double clicking. I have also updated the keyCode for the ENTER key by moving it outside of the function for better performance.

Comment: @alphanumeric I have updated my solution. The cursor will show up right away after double clicking. I have also updated the keyCode for the ENTER key by moving it outside of the function for better performance. Hope this solution helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler,  pass the event and check for the pressed key code with that of ENTER and ESCAPE. If it matches the key code then set the readonly attribute to true.